# Substring of all data frame elements

Tags: r, substring

Consider:

```
x = data.frame(c('ABCD', 'EFGH'), row.names=c('1A', '1B'))
```

I need a substring of each element in the data frame. Something like this:

```
substring(x, 2,4)
```

Comment: This question is pretty vague. For a multi-column `data.frame`, do you want to retain the original `data.frame` structure? Are you just looking for a vector as a result?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could use `sapply`:

```
sapply(x, substring, 2, 4)
```

or, if you want to take only one specific column - say #1 - of the data frame:

```
substring(x[,1], 2, 4)
```

Comment: how can I substring all elements in data frame cutting from the end of the string ? like -3, -1 (it does not work of course)

Comment: You could use `str_sub` from the `stringr` package. It supports negative values for start and end, which count from the end of the string: `stringr::str_sub(x[, 1], start = -3, end = -1)`.